# Format string after read from com device c#

Tags: c#

I've tried to format my string with following code:

```
while (_serialPort.BytesToRead > 0) 
{
    textBox1.Text += string.Format("{0:X2} ", _serialPort.ReadByte());                    
}
```

and the result is `00 00 00 00` (`00 02 95 97` - when is reading from the com device ) my project need the result to look like `000,295`

Comment: so the 97 at the end is irrelevant.. you could just write a function to remove the spaces and output values 3 at a time and put a comma

Comment: please give me an example or a link I'm a beginner and I do not quite handle it

Comment: You are getting binary data from the device, very unlikely that the actual value resembles "295".  Be sure to read the manual, call the device vendor for support if it is not helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should work, but maybe not the best !

I commented the code for better understanding.

```
string incomingData = "00 02 95 97"; // bytes coming from serial port
string sNosapce = Regex.Replace(incomingData, " ", ""); // remove white spaces from string

string wantedString = sNosapce.Substring(0, 6); // take the first 6 chars
string finalResult = wantedString.Insert(3, ","); // insert the comma in the wanted index
Console.WriteLine(finalResult); // here is the final result
```

Edit:

Here is a complete code to do what you need :

```
    string temp = "";
                while (_serialPort.BytesToRead > 0)
                {
                    temp += string.Format("{0:X2} ", _serialPort.ReadByte());
                }

                string sNosapce = Regex.Replace(temp, " ", ""); // remove white spaces from string
                string wantedString = sNosapce.Substring(0, 6); // take the first 6 chars
                textBox1.Text = wantedString.Insert(3, ","); // insert the comma in the wanted index
temp = "";
```

Comment: What's ur question here ?

Comment: "string finalResult = wantedString.Insert(3, ",");"  is trying to put  , after every 3 and i get error and "string wantedString = sNosapce.Substring(0, 6);" i get error length must refer to a location within the string and if i change to a small number like 2 is working but is showing all 8 numbers

Comment: The code I posted works normally. You have to be sure that the incoming data is more that 6, otherwise you'll get exception. 'Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Same thing for the comma position. So it all depends on the string length . You could check the string length before going with the whole process.

Comment: i think the problem is with my string format {0:X2}. With this format i get result 00 00 00 00 i need to find other format that works with your code

Comment: Even the result 00 00 00 00 works with my code. You have to be sure that is the number is 6 or more chars ! I mean 00 00 00 nothing less. Tried the code with 00 00 00 and I got a result : 000,000 so it's working. Just be sure the incoming data is equals to or more than 6 characters like 00 00 00 or more !

Comment: I found on the internet this example for my device Example: the value 2,310  will be send as : 00 23 10 33 from my device for this i need the format

Comment: i get that vale with my application but i don`t know how to display

Comment: Where do you want exactly display it ? console ? textBox ?

Comment: in textBox      textBox1.Text += string.Format("{0:X2} ", _serialPort.ReadByte());

Comment: I have edited the answer to suit your needs. Happy coding :)

Comment: is not working i get the same errors but when i change sNosapce to (0,2) and wantedString to (1,",") i get the result 9,7 from "00 02 95 97" and the normal result is 0,295 and this are the only values that can be set for the program to run

Comment: copy the first code  of my answer and paste it here and Run http://rextester.com/

Comment: i don`t know if is a difference but your incomingData is string incomingData = "00 02 95 97"; and my is  string incomingData = string.Format("{0:X2} ", _serialPort.ReadByte());

Comment: since you are able to format the incoming bytes by this line from ur code : textBox1.Text += string.Format("{0:X2} ", _serialPort.ReadByte()); , there is no difference at all ! Are u sure you are getting the same result every time ?   I mean 00 00 00 00 ? what does ur error saying ?

Comment: my result is 00 02 95 97 every time and the error is: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length'

Comment: I think the problem is the serial port sending data continually and sometimes the data isn't received completely when we try to check the string, so another data is coming and overwrite the completed string and that's why you are facing this problem. if you always get the same length of data ( xx xx xx xx ) then you may check if the string length is 8 then continue with your process, else what until it's finished. I'll update the answer again to add one more if statement.

Comment: i get blank textBox no answer

Comment: How many reads you get from the serial port  per minute ?  maybe you should add some delay before reading again, to give the method some time to calculate and get the values for you. If the data comes so fast, so the string will always change in length I think ! I worked a little with arduino and read from serial port is just a pain. You have to add some delay to handle the data you get.

Comment: i read from the port 1 every 5-10 min ill try to do more research  thank you so much

Comment: Ok it was my fault ! I was reading just one byte ( xx ) from the serial port and then try to calculate with it ! That was the problem since it'll never reach length 6. I edit my code and it should work now .

Comment: you are the best i don`t know how to thank  you you are grate